# Atom Editor - Unset default keybinding and reassign

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

I'd like to set the keybinding for **tree-view:toggle** in Atom to `cmd-b`.

However that keybinding is set by default to **fuzzy-finder:toggle-buffer-finder**

I know I need to *unset* the keybinding in my keymap.cson file before I can reassign, but my attempts thus far prove unsuccessful.

Here's my current keymap.cson file:

```
'.platform-darwin':
  'cmd-b': 'unset'
'atom-text-editor':
  'cmd-b': 'tree-view:toggle'
```

Right now, the keybinding `cmd-b` opens the sidebar, but hitting it again doesn't close it.

Thanks is advanced for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a context issue. You've defined the toggle command in the editor, you have to define it again for the tree-view, or define it for a lower context.

Replace the quoted lines from your keymap.cson with:

```
'.platform-darwin':
  'cmd-b': 'tree-view:toggle'
```